# change visual studio color of active intellisense item

Tags: visual-studio, colors, ide, intellisense

I saw many q&a for altering the color of the intellisense in Visual studio.

My question is a bit different.

Currently, the difference in VS for the current item in intellisense is - it is bold, which is nice. I wish to change the color of it also, so I will see clearly the current parameter I should enter.

[image]

Comment: What’s your VS version? It is better to share a screenshot of “the difference in VS for the current item in intellisense is - it is bold” in https://onedrive.live.com/, I suppose you mean the complete word in the List members and I checked it in some VS versions, there has a background color to help us to distinguish, please check this screenshot: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKmCM4iqsasx2x0sUO

Comment: TY for your quick reply. it is vs2013

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot of your current scenario? Not sure my  previous guess is correct or not, thanks.

Comment: OK, Just did. The first parameter is the active one, and it is bold. I wish I was able to alter the color

Comment: Thank you for your update and I checked it in my VS 2013/2015/2017 and I found start with the VS 2015, the color already default change to blue, please check this: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKmCQg50NsjzGI_NeT, search around there has no such intellisense extension for VS 2013 to modify this color, it is better to upgrade to VS 2015 or VS 2017.